# How to uninstall a theme from tmux while there is no tmux.conf?

Tags: themes, tmux

I installed tmux on my ubuntu using `apt install tmux` and than
I cloned [this theme](https://github.com/wfxr/tmux-power) repository from GitHub and just simply ran the theme script using `./tmux-power.tmux`.

Now that I want to uninstall the theme and head back to the default one, there is no `tmux.conf` file at all.

I removed the cloned repository and also completely uninstalled tmux using `sudo apt-get purge tmux` but still stuck with installed theme.

While I was trying to find `tmux.conf` I found tmux repository at `/usr/share/doc/tmux` but there where no `tmux.conf` either (see image bellow).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.tmux.conf` file should be in your home directory, but it's a hidden file (beginning with a `.`).

Try and run `ls -la` in your homedir, and see if it's there.

If you want a fresh install of tmux, remove the config file in your homedir before reinstalling: 
 `rm ~/.tmux.conf`

Now all tmux config should be reset to default.